# Could we please reopen this question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question

A single diamond moderator decided to close:

[Wrong encoding of "file name from a file handle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430840/wrong-encoding-of-file-name-from-a-file-handle/13430973#13430973)

While I have seen better questions in my day, I have also seen much worse. It is a person who ran into a commonplace pitfall with the Win32 API related to Unicode characters. Upon noticing the closure just now, I edited it to bring the critical bit of code into the question from the Microsoft sample where it was linked.

So, please reopen.

Comment: There is no need to bring this to Meta.  The question is now in the "Reopen" queue and will be reevaluated by the community.

Comment: @iCodez: maybe and maybe not. The [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) may result in a quick positive response here (or just the opposite).

Comment: Yes there is, since a diamond used diamond powers to close it. If it had been ordinary folks, I would not it mentioned it here.

Comment: Mod close votes can be overturned by the community.  You just need 5 reopen votes.

Comment: There are *thousands* of questions about this common mistake.  Hard to see why we need another one.  With fake code that doesn't resemble the OP's mistake no less.  He did **not** get question marks.  This is not useful.

Comment: You chose one interpretation of what he wrote, I chose another. He stated that he was using the code on the other side of a link, I copied _that code_ into his question. If it's a dup, close it as a dup.

Answer (score 7):

You did one of the many things we encourage people to do. You made the question better and in doing so made it survive re-opening.

By editing the question, it was put back in the re-open queue; It does deserve to be open now.

Thank you for taking the time to improve the site by editing a post into shape.

As to why it was closed:

It was flagged as "Not a real question" (back when we had such a thing), and I closed it because it lacked the information in the question itself needed to be answerable.  Today it would have been closed as Off Topic -> Questions must have all information in the question.